# How to increase the size of $\pi$ in the commutative diagram?

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}%[column sep=large]
   E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)\arrow[rr,"\Phi" ]\arrow[dr,swap,"\pi" ]& & U\times \mathbb{R}^k \arrow[dl,"\pi_1" ] \\
      &  U &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

I wish to increase the size of $\pi$ to the size in this one,

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (E) at (0,0) {$E_1$};
\node[right=of E] (F) {$E_2$};

\draw[->] (E)--(F) node [midway,above] (phi) {$h$};
\node[below= 1cm of phi] (A) {$\mathcal{M}$};
\draw[->] (E)--(A.north west) node [midway,below] {$\pi_1$};
\draw[->] (F)--(A.north east) node [midway,right] {$\pi_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to replace `\pi`, `\pi_1`, and `\Phi` in the arguments of the `\arrow` statements with `\textstyle\pi`, `\textstyle\pi_1`, and `\textstyle\Phi`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}%[column sep=large]
   E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U) \arrow[rr,"\textstyle\Phi" ]
                     \arrow[dr,swap,"\textstyle\pi" ]
    & & U\times \mathbb{R}^k 
                     \arrow[dl,"\textstyle\pi_1" ] \\
    & U &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you want to do like that: look at commutative diagrams in fine books and you'll notice that the labels are usually typeset in the size of superscripts.

You can change the size for selected labels adding `\textstyle` to the label, as shown in Mico's answer, but this is boring and error prone if you want to do that for all labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

This is the best style, in my opinion, which is used
in most commutative diagrams in papers and books
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)\arrow[rr,"\Phi" ]\arrow[dr,swap,"\pi" ] &&
  U\times \mathbb{R}^k \arrow[dl,"\pi_1" ] \\
& U
\end{tikzcd}
\]
You can change the behavior locally
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[labels={font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\textstyle}}]
E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)\arrow[rr,"\Phi" ]\arrow[dr,swap,"\pi" ] &&
  U\times \mathbb{R}^k \arrow[dl,"\pi_1" ] \\
& U
\end{tikzcd}
\]
or globally%
\tikzcdset{labels={font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\textstyle}}}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
E|_U:=\pi^{-1}(U)\arrow[rr,"\Phi" ]\arrow[dr,swap,"\pi" ] &&
  U\times \mathbb{R}^k \arrow[dl,"\pi_1" ] \\
& U
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The “local way” will hold only for the diagram in which the option is specified. The `\tikzcd` line for the “global way”, in case you decide for it, should go in the preamble; I put it in the document body only by showing the example.

[image]

Comment: Are you calling my answer boring? :-)

Comment: @Mico No, but the method definitely is.